# How to provide hardcoded path to sourceDir in wix

Tags: wix, heat

I have come up with a wix heat.exe harvest command

```
heat.exe dir ../SessionAPI/Publish -cg C_SessionAPIWebSiteComponent -gg -scom -sreg -sfrag -srd -dr SessionAPIDirectory -var ..\SessionAPI -out ./SessionAPI.wxs
```

This creates .wxs files with Source like below

```
Source="$(..\SessionAPI)\packages.config" />
```

But I don't want the source to point to an environment variable and it should be want it to be like

```
Source="..\SessionAPI\packages.config" />
```

I am not able to achieve it. Can someone please shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XSLT to transform the output generated by Heat. Take a look at this question and the corresponding answer:
[Move from manual component creation to harvesting with the HeatDirectory task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302849/move-from-manual-component-creation-to-harvesting-with-the-heatdirectory-task)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I had done this already a friend helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

Best not to fight the system. Use a variable as Heat expects, and then define that variable in candle.

```
heat.exe -var var.SessionAPI <other options>

candle.exe -dSessionAPI=..\SessionAPI <other options>
```